# What are the performance metrics for Clustering Algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I'm working on Kmeans clustering but unlike supervised learning I cannot figure the performance metrics for clustering algorithms. How to perform the accuracy after training the data?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `kmeans` you can find the `inertia_` of it. Which can give you an idea how well `kmeans` algorithm has worked.

```
kmeans = KMeans(...)
# Assuming you already have fitted data on it.
kmeans.inertia_ # lesser is better
```

Or, alternatively if you call `score()` function, which will give you the same but the sign will be negative. As we assume bigger score means better but for `kmeans` lesser `inertia_` is better. So, to make them consistent an extra negation is applied on it.

```
# Call score with data X
kmeans.score(X) # greater is better
```

This is the very basic form of analyzing performance of `kmeans`. In reality if you take the number of clusters too high the `score()` will increase accordingly (in other words `inertia_` will decrease), because `inertia_` is nothing but the summation of the squared distances from each point to its corresponding cluster's centroid to which cluster it is assigned to. So if you increase the number of the clusters too much, the overall distances' squared summation will decrease as each point will get a centroid very near to it. Although, the quality of clustering is horrible in this case.  So, for better analysis you should find out `silhouette score` or even better use `silhouette diagram` in this case.

You will find all of the implementations in this notebook: [09_unsupervised_learning.ipynb](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/09_unsupervised_learning.ipynb)

The book corresponding to this repository is: [Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow, 2nd Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/). It is a great book to learn all of these details.

Comment: Thanks Hafiz. How to connect with you?

Comment: Scaling should be done first or PCA should be applied first?

Comment: Scaling should be done first, see here: https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2015_pca_in_3_steps.html#standardizing

Comment: How do I know which clustering algorithm works well? for suppose if I use 3 clustering algorithms how do I know which performs better?

Comment: Theoretically speaking, it depends on your data -- If your clusters are almost same sized and spherical then try 'K-Means', if cluster blobs are ellipsoidal in shape then use Gaussian Mixture Model, if you think the cluster can have random shapes but has a continuous region of high density then use 'DBSCAN'.

Comment: For these types of prototyping the library `PyCaret` is super helpful. It requires less coding which is helpful for faster prototyping on various algorithms. For clustering see: https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials.html#clustering Also you will find very good tutorials on it from `YouTube`.